# Create NSMutableArray dynamically, and use selector with parameters on objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nsmutablearray, selector

I'm creating an application, in which i used an `NSMutableArray` to stock some objects. To do this, no problem in first look :

```
ArrayOfViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[ArrayOfViews addObject:...];
```

But my object are UIViews, that i create. For example, I have a file named "Level1". How could I add an object from "Level1", like :

```
Level1 * level1view;
```

decalered in the same UIViewcontroller from my NSMuttableArray ?

Like a sort of :

```
for (i = 0, i < max, i++)
{
    [ArrayOfViews addObject:[objectWithName:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"level%iview", i]]];
}
```

I don't know how could I wrote it with good encoding.

Second, to use the objects with a selector and parameters, how could i do ?

Because i tried :

```
NSString * futureSelector = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Level%iappearswithTime:", number];
SEL s = NSSelectorFromString(futureSelector);
NSInvocation * invoc = [[NSInvocation alloc] init];
[invoc setSelector:s];
[invoc setArgument:&t atIndex:1];
[invoc setTarget:[ArrayOfViews objectAtIndex:number]];
[invoc invoke];
```

To replace this sort of code :

```
[level1view Level1appearswithTime:t];
```

where variable t is an `NSTimeInterval`

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1):

Since variable names are gone during compilation, you essentially can't do this (unless, of course, the variables are instance variables in which case their name is preserved, but then you still don't want to do it, I'm sure.)

As to the selector-and-string-problem: why not use `NSStringFromSelector()`, `NSSelectorFromString()` and `- [NSObject performSelector:withObject:]`?

```
SEL s = NSSelectorFromString([selectorsArray objectAtIndex:0]);
[someObject performSelector:s withObject:42];
```

Comment: I can't do this, i've tried, because when i test this : [[ArrayOfViews objectAtIndex:number] performSelector:s withObject:t];  it gives me : Sending 'NSTimeInterval' (aka 'double') to parameter of incompatible type 'id' (where you put 42)

Comment: @user2057209 Then 1. turn off stupid ARC, 2. google `NSInvocation`. It rocks too, you can specify all sorts of types.

Comment: I've edited with `NSInvocation` (see first post), but it doesn't looks like working.

Comment: @user2057209 What exactly does "it doesn't look like working" mean in your case?

Comment: That the object `[ArrayOfViews objectAtIndex:number]` calls the dynamic selector (create with a string) and one parameter.

Comment: @user2057209 That's cool. In fact, calling a dynamic selector is not something considered as "not working". What is the problem?

Comment: The problem is that this code, [level1view Level1appearswithTime:t]; works well, but it's call directly, and dynamically like i put in my first post it doesn't work